If I make a USDT withdrawal on the Ethereum network and the last digit of the address was missing, would the transaction fail or will it be lost?
If I make a USDT withdrawal on the Ethereum network and the last digit of the address was missing, would the transaction fail or will it be lost?
0x7d5AB9E259D5B0612C193829378Ce2ed106C4c25
Or
0x7d5AB9E259D5B0612C193829378Ce2ed106C4c2
The exchange that I was due it from claimed that I missed the last number, but they do not provide me with any ability to check the transactions. They sent me a picture that just showed the number missing. It’s my contention that if the address isn’t correct the transaction will never be Initiated, and it will fail.
I suspect fraud but I need proof

The transaction should fail.
The exchange should have a mechanism to check the validity of the address. Checking the address length is the most basic error checking mechanism.
Even if the transaction goes through on the exchange, the Ethereum protocol should reject the transaction because the address is invalid.
You should ask them to give you the transaction hash if they keep claiming the transaction went through.
